# Guzzle Not Sending Headers From Form MultiPart

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am using `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",` and trying to post a file to an API endpoint. The file posts fine when using RequestBin but the API is not getting the header it requires. The Header is not sent to Request bin either. According to the docs, I need to do an array of associative arrays. http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#post-form-requests

However, this is not working. Here's the Guzzle request:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => '127.0.0.1:3000']);
        $response = $client->request('POST', '/process', [
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name'     => 'file',
                    'contents' => $file,
                    'bucketName' => 'test',
                    'headers'  => ['X-API-Key' => 'abc345']
                ],
            ]
        ]);
```

What am I doing wrong that it's not sending the header?

Thank you very much,

Josh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Headers is an $option, that's mean it must be at the same level as multipart.

```
<?php
      $response = $client->request('POST', '/process', [
        'multipart' => [
            [
                'name' => 'file',
                'contents' => 'test',
                'bucketName' => 'test',
            ],
        ],
        'headers' => ['X-API-Key' => 'abc345'] // <------- HERE
    ]);
```

Comment: The documentation specifically says to put it in the multipart area. Also, if I do as you suggested I get a new error, "A Contents key is a required"

Comment: Which headers we are talking about? If it's about HTTP headers before any body - than my answer is correct. I checked with TCPDUMP

Comment: Look what am i talking about: http://pastebin.com/iTRFWMsi 1 - my version, 2 - yours.

Comment: I was getting the brackets wrong indeed. Thank you.

Comment: Documentation made me pull my hairs for some time, looks like some thing wrong with the docs, above method is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You were probably using **multipart** in conjunction with **form_params** , this is not explicitly explained in the documentation of laravel but guzzle won't work with both

> Note
>
> multipart cannot be used with the form_params option. You will need to
> use one or the other. Use form_params for
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded requests, and multipart for
> multipart/form-data requests.
>
> This option cannot be used with body, form_params, or json

To solve this problem you will need to parse all the params to multipart, if you are using laravel or lumen you can do it in this way

```
if(!empty($this->files))
                {

                 //if there is an image parse all the rest parameters to 
                 // multipart

                  $file_keys=array_keys($this->files);

                  foreach($this->files as $k => $file)
                  {
                  $http = $http->attach($k, file_get_contents($file),$k);
                  }

                  foreach($this->data as $dk =>&$d)
                  {
                     if(!in_array($dk,$file_keys))
                     {
                        if(is_array($d))
                        {
                           $d=json_encode($d);
                        }

                        $http = $http->attach($dk,$d);
  
                     }

                  }

                  return $http=$http->post($this->url);
 
                }
                //if there isn't any file just send all as form_params

               return $http=$http->post($this->url,$this->data);
```